# Powershell - Arrays all on one line

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell so don't know a huge amount.

I have a menu and I have 2 options ("Add IP" and "List IP's")

The "Add IP" code is:

```
$UIP = Read-Host "Enter IP to whitelist"
$whitelist += $UIP
```

The "List IP" code is:

```
Write-Host "==== $Title Whitelist IPs ===="
Write-Host
Write-Host $whitelist
```

The only problem is that when I list the array it lists everything on the same line like this:

```
192.168.0.1192.168.0.2
```

when I would like to to display like this:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
```

Comment: You could use foreach and print one element at a time.

Comment: Did you define $whitelist as an array?  See this StackOverflow answer which seems relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676960/array-output-to-multiple-lines

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @lx07 that gave me the answer, correct code is:
`[array]$whitelist += $UIP`

Comment: @Sam.92 Please post that as an answer.

Comment: Read [PowerShell back to basics: the arrays](https://pwrshell.net/back-to-basics-arrays/) article. Predeclare an array as `$whitelist = New-Object -typeName System.Collections.ArrayList` or briefly as `$whitelist = @()`; then, apply `Write-Host $whitelist -Separator ([environment]::NewLine)`.

Answer (score 9):

You do not have to use a loop to perfom this, if you do not want to perform any operations on each IP.

Simply use

```
Write-Host ($whitelist -join "`n")
```

This will inject a new line between each element in the array. I have compared the differences below:

```
$array = @('foo','bar')
write-host ($array -join "`n") 

Output:
foo
bar
```

versus

```
$array = @('foo','bar')
write-host $array

Output:
foo bar
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
Write-Host $elements -Separator "`n"
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-3.0

Answer (score -1):

You can user the for loop for to achieve this

for ($loopindex = 0; $loopindex  -lt $whitelist.Count; $loopindex ++)
{
    $whitelist[$loopindex]
}